# Sparse Matrix Cholesky decomposition Rcpp Eigen

Tags: sparse-matrix, rcpp

I'm dealing with a big sparse matrix (10k x 10k variance/covariance matrix, so symmetric and positive definite) in R. I need a fast way to find the Cholesky decomposition of that matrix. I understand that using [SparseLU](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/classEigen_1_1SparseLU.html#a5eb96e32259c4d8a56ff7106e2aa5a78) from RcppEigen package can be a solution but I can't figure out how it works.

In the next script, I put the example of my function in R. It loads a SparseMatrix SS, of which I need the Cholesky decomposition. I'd like to have the same output as chol(SS), with typical R function chol.

```
cholScript<-'using Eigen::Map; 
using Eigen::SparseMatrix;

const SparseMatrix<double> Sigma(as<SparseMatrix<double> >(Sigma));
using namespace Rcpp;

// compute C, the Cholesky decomposition of Sigma

return wrap(C);'

cxxfunction(signature(Sigma = "dgCMatrix"), cholScript, plugin = "RcppEigen")
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I think that this can be a solution:

```
CholeskyCppSparse<-'using Eigen::Map; 
using Eigen::SparseMatrix;
using Eigen::LLT;
const SparseMatrix<double> SS(as<SparseMatrix<double> >(Sigma));

typedef Eigen::SimplicialLLT<SparseMatrix<double> > SpChol;

const SpChol Ch(SS);
return wrap(Ch.matrixL());'

CholSparse <- cxxfunction(signature(Sigma = "dgCMatrix"), CholeskyCppSparse, plugin = "RcppEigen")
```

Change matrixL for matrixU if you want the upper triangular part of the decomposition (as for chol() function in R).